What is it called when someone exaggerates pronunciation of word for emphasis?
I can think of two examples that I have heard many times…
Drawing out or almost stuttering parts of a word as in saying “wh-h-h-at?” to express extreme disbelief. The goal seems to be to add imaginary syllables to emphasize the word and thus the level of disbelief.
Another example could be combining pronunciation with a laugh as in “a-a-r-r-e you kidding?” Again, expressing extreme disbelief.
If there is no simple phrase or word describing this, I would suggest it be called maspronunciation.

stretching words, also elongating or lengthening (all synonyms of drawing out) used to describe texts more so than verbal emphasizing. There are many specific terms for types of literary repetition, but none found for this. :-( Welcome and good luck.

Notice: only the vowels can be drawn out.

@Lambie ... unless you stutter.

@Mitch I had a 'uge discussion about this on the Spanish site. Even if you repeat sounds with a stutter, you are repeating a vowel sound after the consonant. You cannot repeat a consonant without one.  In fact, all consonants when spoken imply a vowel sound. The letter t [tee], the letter k [kay], etc. My stut-tut-ter.

@Lambie True, but it kind of amounts to the same thing. But we don't use repeated consonants for emphasis like we do with drawn out vowels.

@Lambie Perhaps a better example of emphasizing consonants would be Larry David's "pretty, pretty good": https://www.acmi.net.au/stories-and-ideas/curb-your-enthusiasm-pretty-pretty-pretty/

@Lambie I was funning... But I propose to you that you -can- 'draw out' nasals (n, m, ng) and liquids (l, r) but not semivowels (y, w) at least in English... Are those the syllabic consonants?

@Mitch You cannot make the sound of a consonant in a word without a vowel sound. Nasals especially cannot be drawn out. Funning=two vowels sounds. He rang the bell with ng drawn out becomes ranguh.

Hmmm… I think I just found an answer to my own question. I was thinking about how Vivian Leigh (playing Scarlett O’Hara) could get almost three syllables out of the word war. Even if they weren’t actual syllables, she managed to get three distinct sounds and drew them out to express her frustration and disgust. I’m thinking particularly of that early scene where she threatens to go in the house if she hears the word war again. As for answering my own question, I  came across the word affectation - in speech or writing; artificial and designed to impress.

@Lambie mmmmmmm

@Mitch Yeah, that was tried on me before. mmmm is not a word. It's just a version of humming. In fact, you can't just say the m. [em, see?]
